# Facebook Graph API Explorer and User App

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I started developing and Android Native App with Facebook API (version 3.5).
I followed the Facebook [Getting Started](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-android/) help page and I created an Android Native App on Facebook Developer page.

My interest is to get the user likes, so I set `user_likes` in Permissions settings page.
I'm testing the Facebook App using the Graph API Explorer tool (available in Facebook Developer) with the query `/me/likes`.

The thing that I noticed is that if I run the query `/me/likes` using as application "First Android App" (that is the name of my app) I get much less results than if I run the query with the application "Graph API Explorer" and I don't understand why.

The permissions of the app seems to be correct, if I run the query `/me/permissions` on both applications ("First Android App" and "Graph API Explorer") I obtain the same result:

```js
"data": [
{
  "installed": 1, 
  "basic_info": 1, 
  "user_likes": 1, 
  "user_friends": 1
}
],
```

I also noticed that using FQL query method, with a query like this:

```sql
SELECT page_id, type, name
FROM page
WHERE page_id IN (
    SELECT uid, page_id, type
    FROM page_fan
    WHERE uid=me()
)
```

I can get all my likes even if I use as application "First Android App", so it seems to be a problem that comes up when I try to use the Graph API.

Comment: Set the field `limit` to 500 or above `me/likes?limit=500`